# group by get single item + PK

Tags: mysql

Lets say I had the value

```
PK |  Section | UserID | Rating |  Body
 1          20       30        8   Test
 2          20       31        5  Test2
 3          21       31        6  Test3
```

Something like this came from a subquery. What I want is for each section I'd like to get the higest rating. So 1 should win (higher rating then 2) and 3 should win (its the only one for that section). How do I write this? I was thinking of doing limit 1 but that wont work because I have multiple sections. Also its a subquery so it would be annoying to try to join again.

Comment: You need to show us the query.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk it's a fairly obvious query

Comment: @ChristianStewart I hope you're right.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk I guess maybe "this came from a subquery" could make you wonder if it's doing anything special to get that result, maybe manipulating column names or something

Comment: @ChristianStewart That's why I requested it.

Answer (score 3):

You want only one result per Section (so you want to group by that field) and you want the results that contains the maximum Rating.  You have to use the HAVING clause here because of the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT _____ FROM ______ GROUP BY Section HAVING Rating = MAX(Rating)
```

Comment: Oh... I got confused because the question says "So 1 should win (higher rating then 2)...", I will correct.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I undid the accept (but left +1) because i tested and it didnt work. For some reason max gives me one row while min gave me two (dafuq). It also appears if i sort the subquery so my ideal row is first of the group thats what i get when i do select * in the outer query with its group by

Its bizarre. I have to do sql server at work and although i couldnt figure this out until someone showed me rank by partition, it at least seemed to all make sense and didnt seem fragile or weird

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can sort like this:

`ORDER BY Rating ASC`
or
`ORDER BY Rating DESC`

Asc being ascending, and Desc being descending. You can also use `LIMIT 1` after that to just get the highest rating.

Now, you want to get it for each section. To do this, you can use `WHERE` to select just that section. If you want to get the top ratings for each section, you would likely (if I'm not mistaken) have to go through each section number and query the highest item.

Comment: But if I do limit 1 I need to run a new query. I'm trying to get both sections in one query